# iOS not scrolling horizontally on initial load

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs

Okay, so I have been having this issue with ios when scrolling and I have been trying to debug this for a couple of days now and I'm still no closer to a solution.

#### Problem

On iOS when you first load the page, the preview/image scroller just locks up (you're unable to scroll).

It seems to be very flakey as sometimes it wont work and sometimes it will.

#### Links

https://wonderbly.com/personalized-products/lost-my-name-book/preview?name=Edwin&phototype=type-iii&base=&locale=en-US&gender=boy

https://wonderbly.com/personalized-products/my-little-monster-name-book/preview?name=Edwin&locale=en-GB&base=

https://wonderbly.com/personalized-products/the-birthday-thief-book/preview?name=Edwin&base=&locale=en-GB&gender=boy&phototype=type-iii

https://wonderbly.com/personalized-products/roald-dahl-my-golden-ticket-book/preview?name=Edwin&base=&surname=Joseph&locale=en-US&gender=boy

https://wonderbly.com/personalized-products/the-journey-home-book/preview?name=Edwin&base=&locale=en-GB&gender=boy&phototype=type-iii

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Load any one of the links above on iOS
2. Keep reloading until preview is not scrollable
3. Failure point

#### Points of interests

**HTML:**

```
<div class="scrolling-book-scrollable agitated-monkey" style="overflow: scroll;">
  <!-- Width changes depending on the amount of images -->
  <div class="scrolling-book" style="width: 10168px;"> 
    <!-- A lot of divs with images inside that get added client side and changes if you change the options -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.scrolling-book-scrollable {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}

.scrolling-book-scrollable.agitated-monkey {
  .scrolling-book {
    animation: agitated 4s infinite $bezier-out forwards;
  }
}

@keyframes agitated {
  10% {
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  20% {
    transform: none;
  }
}
```